# Is 32GB a hard limit for SDHC, even if the FAT32 format card is >32GB?

Tags: settings, sdhc

FAT32 drives can be larger than 32GB.  If I format a 64GB SDXC card as FAT32, will all 64GB be recognized by SDHC devices that proclaim a 32GB limitation?  Is the 32GB limitation "hard coded" or is it arbitrary?  Does the real limit vary from device to device?

Comment: First of all not every formatting software allows you to format a 64GB drive as FAT32 (the reason is unknown), but accessing any drive larger than 32GB is no problem at all. If you really want to be sure that your drive is properly formatted, put it in your Android device and format it in `Settings->Storage->Delete SD storage (or similar)`. Most of the time it formats your drive with the newer `exFAT` file system which allows drive sizes of up to 128 PiB and file sizes up to 16 EiB, as well as other advantages over old FAT file systems.